# Extract image from video for print at 300 dpi instead of 72 dpi

Tags: image, video, blender

I made a video of some landscape with a camera.
After connecting the camera to a tv screen and playing the video, it all rendered wiredly (bug) but beautifully (a bit like impressionism).
As the camera was busy, I used a smartphone to record a video of the tv screen.
I then extracted one image from that video and would like to have it printed out with a target print size of 60 x 34 cm (23.6 x 13.4 inches) at 300 dpi.

**PROCESS**

**Recording the tv screen**

The smartphone is a Galaxy Note 3 which is said to have a 386.47 ppp pixel density (might only be the display pixel density).
The video was shot at a resolution of 1920 x 1080 px, which is the default video resolution.

**Copying the video to computer**

My computer runs Windows 8.1, and when checking the video properties, here is what I get :

- Resolution = 1920 x 1080
- Data rank =  16973 Kbits/s
- Total rank (in bits) = 17096 Kbits/s
- Fps = 30

**Extracting image**

I used Blender video editor to export one image (frame) from the video with the below settings.

*Input (Dimensions) :*

- Resolution : X = 1920, Y = 1080, Scale = 100%
- Aspect ratio : X = 1, Y = 1
- Frame rate : 30 fps
- Time remapping : Old = 100, New = 100

*Ouput :*

- File format : TIFF
- Mode : RGBa
- Color Depth : 16
- Compression: none

**Checking image properties**

When checking the properties (right click on the file), the image has the following properties :

- Dimensions = 1920 x 1080
- Resolution X and Y = 72 ppp
- Color depth = 64
- Compression = none
- Resolution unit = 2

**Opening image with image editor**

When checking the image size here is what is says :

*Scale and size :*

- Size = 1920 x 1020
- Resolution X and Y = 72 pixels/inch

*Print size :*

- size = 67.73 x 38.1 cm (26.67 x 15 inches)
- Resolution X and Y = 72 pixels/inch

I tried to change the dpi of the image to 300 but the dimensions shrinked to 16.2 x 9.1 cm (6.4 x 3.6 inches).
*Note :* color of depth changed to 8 bits as Gimp currently can't open 16 bits pictures, so I will probably need to use another image editor instead.

**QUESTIONS**

**Q1 :** How can I know the original pixel density of the video, as I can't find that information in the video settings of the phone ?

**Q2 :** If the actual pixel density of the video is higher that 72 dpi, why would Blender shrink it to 72 when outputting to an image ?

**Q3 :** Why is the value of the color depth 64 after extraction when checking the properties ? Does it mean Blender changed it from 16 bits to 8 bits ?

**Q4 :** Is there a way using Blender to parameter the dpi of the ouput image ? 
The addon "Print to render" can't be activated nor installed, most likely because I have Blender v2.79 and the addon seems to only work with v2.53.

**Q5 :** Is there any other piece of software able to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print 23.6 inches x 13.4 inches at 300 dpi, you are going to need an image of 7,080 x 4,020 pixels.

So, use **ImageMagick**, **GIMP** or **Photoshop** to resize your image to that size. You will probably find you don’t have enough quality for this though, since it is a 3x enlargement.

Comment: Not sure if it is still the case, but it used to be that it was better to go from 2,000 pixels to 7,000 pixels in steps rather than all in one go, e.g. go from 2,000 to 3,000 to 4,000 to 5,000 to 6,000 to 7,000 instead of directly from 2,000 to 7,000 in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mark, but my questions are more related to the pixel density of the video itself. I'd like to know why the pixel density seems to have changed from the phone to Blender video editor. Or from Blender video editor to the final image. And if there are any ways to avoid that.

Comment: The pixel density is largely irrelevant - until you come to print an image. What I am saying is that the actual number of pixels you have is all that counts. The density is just a number - it doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you captured 1,920 pixels in width, you only have 1,920 pixels across. To print 23.6 inches wide and lay down 300 pixels per inch, you need 7,080 pixels. The resolution is irrelevant - it's just a number. You need to up-rez, or up-sample, or up-size your image (or whatever anyone wants to call it) to get more pixels.

Comment: Alright, I got it and I know there are different tools out there which can up-rez images. The only unsolved question I have is the difference between the supposedly initial 386.47ppp of the phone versus those 72ppp of the image. That doesn't make any sense to me. Are they 2 completely different things ?

Comment: Yes, that pertains to the display. It is 2.8in x 5in and 1080x1920 pixels, so `1080/2.8` = `1920/5` = 385ppi.

Comment: Alright, then the image I get is what it is and the only option I have is to up-rez it or up-sample it. Thank you for your time and input Mark.